ControlValueAccessor using implemented formatand parser in form fieldcheckbox but Input data is changing ,it is not reflecting checkbox
one TrueFalseValueComponent used for if checkbox is checked , I will get 1, if checked is false i will get 0.
For example I am selected first record selection value 0. Now checkbox is not checked. I am checked box. I am clicking second row but selection 0 but checkbox is showing checked. How to fix the issue
    import {
      Component,
      Directive,
      HostBinding,
      HostListener,
      Input,
      Output,
      EventEmitter,
    } from '@angular/core';
    import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import {
      FormsModule,
      NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      NgControl,
      ControlValueAccessor,
    } from '@angular/forms';
    import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-true-false-value',
      standalone: true,
      template: `
        <input type="checkbox" [checked]="_value === this.trueValue" (input)="valueChange($event)"/>
      `,
      providers: [
        {
          provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
          multi: true,
          useExisting: TrueFalseValueComponent,
        },
      ],
    })
    export class TrueFalseValueComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
      _value = 0;
      @Input()
      value: any;
      onChange = (value: any) => {};
      onTouched = () => {};
      touched = false;
      disabled = false;
      @Input() trueValue: any = 1; // some time true
      @Input() falseValue: any = 0; // sometime true
    
      writeValue(value: number) {
        this._value = value;
      }
    
      registerOnChange(onChange: any) {
        this.onChange = onChange;
      }
    
      registerOnTouched(onTouched: any) {
        this.onTouched = onTouched;
      }
    
      markAsTouched() {
        if (!this.touched) {
          this.onTouched();
          this.touched = true;
        }
      }
    
      setDisabledState(disabled: boolean) {
        this.disabled = disabled;
      }
    
      valueChange(event: any) {
        const value = event.target.checked;
        this.markAsTouched();
        this.onChange(value ? '1' : '0');
      }
    }
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      imports: [FormsModule, TrueFalseValueComponent, CommonModule],
      standalone: true,
      template: `
   @Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  imports: [FormsModule, TrueFalseValueComponent, CommonModule],
  standalone: true,
  template: `
 <label> Select Row </label>
 <select  [(ngModel)]="selectRow" name="selectRow"  (ngModelChange)="modelChanged($event)">
 <option [ngValue]="0">Row 0</option>
        <option [ngValue]="1">Row 1</option>
        <option [ngValue]="2">Row 2</option>
        <option [ngValue]="3">Row 3</option>
        </select>



    <form #f="ngForm">
        <app-true-false-value name="options" [(ngModel)]="data.option"  />
        <br/>
        <select  [(ngModel)]="data.selection" name="selection">
        <option [ngValue]="1">option 1</option>
        <option [ngValue]="2">option 2</option>
        <option [ngValue]="3">option 3</option>
        </select>
        <br/> 
        <input type="text"  name="Text1" [disabled]="data.selection!==1" [(ngModel)]="data.Text1" />
        <input type="text"  name="Text2" [disabled]="data.selection!==2" [(ngModel)]="data.Text2" />
        <input type="text"  name="Text3" [disabled]="data.selection!==3" [(ngModel)]="data.Text3" />
    </form>

    {{f.form.value | json}}
   `,
    })
    export class App {
      name = 'Angular';
    
    
    tableData=[
    {
    id:1
    option: 0,
        selection: 1,
        Text1: 'Text1',
        Text2: 'Text2',
        Text3: 'Text3',
    },
    {
    id:2
    option: 0,
        selection: 1,
        Text1: 'Text1',
        Text2: 'Text2',
        Text3: 'Text3',
    }
    {
    id:3
    option: 0,
        selection: 1,
        Text1: 'Text1',
        Text2: 'Text2',
        Text3: 'Text3',
    }
    {
    id:4
    option: 1,
        selection: 1,
        Text1: 'Text1',
        Text2: 'Text2',
        Text3: 'Text3',
    }
    ];
    data:any={}
    constructor{
    this.data=tableData[0]
    }
    
    addToList(index:any){
    this.data=tableData[insdex];
     }

URL  : https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-5ktdwy?file=src%2Fmain.ts
Even I tried with ngonchanges

in your valueChanged you forgot give value to _value
  valueChange(event: any) {
    const value = event.target.checked;
    this._value=value ? 1 : 0; //<--also give value to "_value"
    this.markAsTouched();
    this.onChange(value ? 1 : 0);
  }

BTW you can remove the ngOnChanges (It's used if you change the values of the "Inputs" , and ngAfterViewChecked (the this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges() is used when changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush (and not in anyplace)
